# if Struct item equalling nil

Tags: swift, uitableview, struct, admob

I have a tableView that I am attempting to fill with ads every certain number of times. I am using a struct to store my variables.

```
struct postStruct
{
    var image : UIImage?
    var label : String?
    var captions : String?
    var ad: GADNativeExpressAdView?
}
```

I am then appending certain things at certain places. I am having a problem with my if statement in my tableview where I want to load the ads in if the variable does not equal nil. Here is my current code which just fills up the whole tableview with regular cells in the else statement. I suspect it may have something to do with the indexPath but I have tried all given ones.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    if arrayOfPosts[indexPath.row].ad != nil{
        let adView = arrayOfPosts[indexPath.row].ad
        let reusableAdCell = tableViewOne.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("NativeExpressAd", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NativeExpressAd

        for subView in reusableAdCell.contentView.subviews {
            subView.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        reusableAdCell.addSubview(adView!)
        adView?.center = reusableAdCell.contentView.center
       return reusableAdCell
    }
    else{
        let cell = tableViewOne.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("popularCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PopTableViewCell
        return cell
    }
}
```

Here are the two times I fill the arrayOfPosts

```
func getData()
{
    arrayOfPosts = [
        postStruct.init(image: UIImage(named: "profileIcon-1") , label: "Test 1", captions: "Test 1", ad: nil),
        postStruct.init(image: UIImage(named: "profileICONTRY3-1") , label: "Test 2", captions: "Test 2", ad: nil),
        postStruct.init(image: UIImage(named: "self") , label: "Test 3", captions: "Test 3", ad: nil),
        postStruct.init(image: UIImage(named: "profileIcon-1") , label: "Test 4", captions: "Test 4", ad: nil), postStruct.init(image: UIImage(named: "profileICONTRY3-1") , label: "Test 5", captions: "Test 5", ad: nil),
        postStruct.init(image: UIImage(named: "self") , label: "Test 6", captions: "Test 6", ad: nil)
    ]




}
```

And here's where I get the Ad

```
func NativeAdsExpress


{
    var index = 2
    let size = GADAdSizeFromCGSize(CGSize(width: adWidth, height: adHeight))
    while index < arrayOfPosts.count
    {
        let adView = GADNativeExpressAdView(adSize: size)
        adView?.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-6067365138487039/8892521700"
        adView?.rootViewController = self
        adView?.delegate = self
        let new = postStruct(image: nil, label: nil, captions: nil, ad: adView)
        adToLoad.append(adView!)
        arrayOfPosts.insert(new, atIndex: index)
        tableViewOne.reloadData()
        index += adInterval
    }


}
```

Comment: So are you sure your dataSource actually delivers any struct where the `ad != nil`? Have you inspected `arrayOfPosts`?

Comment: Also the `tableViewOne.reloadData()` seems like an app-crashing infinite-loop waiting to happen.

Comment: it is not swift3? on swift 3 your signature should be `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
  cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`

Comment: can you add the code where you fill the `arrayOfPosts`

Comment: Just added it and removed reload data, and no im not on swift 3 im on 2.3

Answer (score 1):

We assume that arrayOfPosts has as many elements as cells will have the table. Otherwise you may have an error index outside of array or anything else.
If you have a cell to put ad, you should only assign the values to the cell ad. I do not understand why you put a reload table inside the cell. If you are in this method is because the table is reloading.
The NativeExpressAd cell should have a view inside the type GADNativeExpressAdView or type UIView (depends on what GADNativeExpressAdView has to display the information) called for example adView and you should only assign to that view the contents of the struct, more or less like this:

```
     reusableAdCell.adView = arrayOfPosts[indexPath.row].ad
     return reusableAdCell
```

You could display the code of the NativeExpressAd cell

**UPDATE:**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    if arrayOfPosts[indexPath.row].ad != nil{
       let adView = arrayOfPosts[indexPath.row].ad
       let reusableAdCell = tableViewOne.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("NativeExpressAd", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NativeExpressAd

       reusableAdCell.adView = adView
       return reusableAdCell
    } else{
       let cell = tableViewOne.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("popularCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PopTableViewCell
       // put values of cell, label, caption, etc
       return cell
    }
```

}

Comment: with this solution he don't need to remove all subviews and add a new subview. much less todo for the app

Comment: This seems nice but I need a good if statement and yeah I got rid of reload data

Comment: So for some reason when I do what you said with the adView it doesnt display anything in the view

Comment: Do you have a UIView in the cell? How do you have the cell declared ? What items do you have?

Comment: let reusableAdCell = tableViewOne.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("NativeExpressAd", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NativeExpressAd, NativeExpressAd is a UITableViewCell subclass, isn't it?

Comment: Yes NativeAdExpress the name of Cell I made, and I did put a view in the cell but my main problem is that I do not know how to cycle through my struct so that the ads appear in the cell [indexPath.row] does nothing.

Comment: Then your problem is not in the cell, it is in the model. I think that you have generated arrayOfPost with data or with ad, as you have wanted, and when you want to show the cell, show ad or data according to the value of ad. If so, it is easier than what you have implemented. I'll modify the answer. If it does not appear ad, maybe you have to check the form that ad to be shown

Comment: Another thing you can do to verify that ad is displayed correctly, is to make an array of ad only. With that you have 1 element is sufficient and check that it is shown

Comment: Hey so I've been doing arrayOfPosts[indexPath.row].ad in the if and weirdly if I do that the if is never executed but another cell does appear it is just a Pop Cell. Also I made the arrayOfAds and tried that but when that is executed the other cell does show up only there is no add in it. Could you maybe take a look at my function where I create the ads. I really appreciate the help this is my first time working with Admob.